# asp.net form with action url and button click not working

Tags: asp.net, forms, submit

I am integrating payment gateway in my product. I have to submit a page to third party payment provider. In the page I have asp.button on the click event I want to store the username and amount in the session,When I click the button the page posting to the action url, my click event is not called.
How can I get the value from session and then I want to post the page.
here is the code

Regards
Arun

```
 <form  runat="server" method="post" action="https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/test/order.asp"  id="form1" name="form1" >
                        <!-- General information for the order -->

                        <input type="hidden" name="orderID" value="34567"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="pspid" value="TESTMAS"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="version" value="ncol_2.0"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en_US"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="EUR"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="weightunit" value="kg"/>
                          <input type="hidden" name="accepturl" value="http://localhost:57249/pages/acceptPayment.aspx"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="exceptionurl" value="http://localhost:57249/payment/pages/exception.aspx"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="declineurl" value="http://localhost:57249/payment/pages/decline.aspx"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="cancelurl" value="http://localhost:57249/payment/pages/cancel.aspx"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="homeurl" value="http://localhost:57249/payment/updatePayment.aspx"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="catalogurl" value="http://localhost:57249/payment/updatePayment.aspx"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="SHASign" value="SHA-1"/>


                        <!-- or Template Page -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="TP" value="<Your template page URL>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemid" value="1"  />
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemname" value="Papercut Balance updation" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemdesc" value="Papercut Balance updation" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="taxincluded" value="0" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemvatcode" value="1" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemvat" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemcomments" value="Papercut Balance updation" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemquant" value="1" />
                        <!-- First item of the order -->

                        <table>

                            <tr>
                                <td>username</td>
                                <td>  <asp:TextBox ID="txtusername"  Text="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Payable Amount</td>
                                <td> <asp:TextBox ID="itemprice" Text=""  runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1" >

                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ProceedToPay" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                        </form>


 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String userName = Request["txtusername"];
        Double amount = Convert.ToDouble(Request["itemprice"]);

        try
        {
            Session["username"] = userName;
            Session["amount"] = amount;
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e2.Message + " " + e2.Source);
        }

    }
```

Comment: you need to delete the event and event name assigned to the button then go to design and go to button even properties go to onClick event double click next to it, it will generate event and it automatically assigns event name to the button. Try that way and check

Comment: Hello Nad, thanks for your replay, when I click the button it is posting/transgerring to thirdparty url, my button click not working, i was not able to get the username and item price in session,